# R Causal Impact - confidence bands not plotting

Tags: r

Using the demo as per the causal impact documentation at https://google.github.io/CausalImpact/CausalImpact.html:

I have a time series generated by:

```
library(CausalImpact)

set.seed(1)
x1 <- 100 + arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.999), n = 100)
y <- 1.2 * x1 + rnorm(100)
y[71:100] <- y[71:100] + 10
data <- cbind(y, x1)

pre.period <- c(1, 70)
post.period <- c(71, 100)

impact <- CausalImpact(data, pre.period, post.period)

plot(impact)
```

This code should produce lineplots with confidence bands. However, for me it only produces these bare-looking plots:

[image]

I have tried a fresh installation of all packages as well as running on both vanilla R and RStudio, but got the same result. What can I try to produce the same plots as in the demo? My session info is:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] CausalImpact_1.2.3  bsts_0.9.2          xts_0.11-2         
[4] zoo_1.8-6           BoomSpikeSlab_1.2.1 Boom_0.9.3         
[7] MASS_7.3-51.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3       igraph_1.2.4.2   magrittr_1.5     tidyselect_0.2.5
 [5] munsell_0.5.0    colorspace_1.4-1 lattice_0.20-38  R6_2.4.1        
 [9] rlang_0.4.2      stringr_1.4.0    plyr_1.8.5       dplyr_0.8.3     
[13] tools_3.5.2      grid_3.5.2       gtable_0.3.0     lazyeval_0.2.2  
[17] assertthat_0.2.1 tibble_2.1.3     lifecycle_0.1.0  crayon_1.3.4    
[21] farver_2.0.1     reshape2_1.4.3   purrr_0.3.3      ggplot2_3.2.1   
[25] glue_1.3.1       labeling_0.3     stringi_1.4.3    compiler_3.5.2  
[29] pillar_1.4.3     scales_1.1.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug with `CausalImpact` version 1.2.3. Since posting this question, a new version of `CausalImpact` (1.2.4) has become available on CRAN. The bug can be fixed by

`install.packages('CausalImpact')`

It turned out that the impact_plot.R file was using

```
# Add prediction intervals
q <- q + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
                     data, fill = "SlateGray2")
```

But now `SlateGray2` is no longer recognised and so the code needed to be changed to

```
  # Add prediction intervals
  q <- q + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
                       data, fill = "slategray2")
```

https://github.com/google/CausalImpact/issues/36